# How do I configure multiple datasourses (Oracle and MongoDB) in JHipster?

Tags: java, oracle, mongodb, jhipster

I need to use an Oracle DB for User authentication and for the rest of the entities in the project I need to use MongoDB, is there any way to add multiple datasources to Jhipster for this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JHipster only works with one single DataSource. Otherwise the number of possibilities are just so complex that we just can't generate all types of combinaisons.

What you could do is generate both an SQL and a MongDB project, and merge them manually. As you only use your SQL database for authentication, keep the MongoDB application your main project, and you should be able to continue working on it.